# How to remove POJO class name from the output string?

Tags: java, output, tostring, jooq, pojo

I have below POJO

```
package com.beans.test;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Person {

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private Integer age;

    private Boolean isEmployed;

    private String address;

}
```

Query to fetch Person info

```
public class testTable {

public Person getPersonInfo(final int id) {

return dsl.select(PERSON_INFO.NAME,
                  PERSON_INFO.AGE,
                  PERSON_INFO.IS_EMPLOYED,
                  PERSON_INFO.ADDRESS)
          .from(PERSON_INFO)
          .where(PERSON_INFO.ID.equals(id))
          .fetchOneInto(Person.class)
}
}
```

I need to print the output of the query as string.

```
Person person = testTable.getPersonInfo(id);
String personInfo = person.toString();
System.out.println("personInfo = ", personInfo);
```

Output :-
`personInfo = Person(name=TestName,age=TestAge,isEmployed=true,address=TestAddress)`

Desired Ouput :-
`personInfo = name=TestName,age=TestAge,isEmployed=true,address=TestAddress`

How can I remove the POJO class name from the desired output string ?(As shown in the Desired Output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My solution**

```
package com.company;

import lombok.Data;

public class Main {

    @Data
    public static class Person {

        private int id;

        private String name;

        private Integer age;

        private Boolean isEmployed;

        private String address;

    }

    public static String getClassName(Class clazz){
        if(clazz.getDeclaringClass() == null)
        {
            return clazz.getSimpleName();
        }
        return getClassName(clazz.getDeclaringClass()) + "." + clazz.getSimpleName(); //Recursive - complete class name.
    }

    public static String toStringRemovingClassName(Object obj)
    {
        String pattern = String.format("^%s\\(|\\)$", getClassName(obj.getClass())); //Matches "<ClassName>(" at begin or ")" at end.
        return obj.toString().replaceAll(pattern, "");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var person = new Person();
        System.out.println("personInfo = " + toStringRemovingClassName(person));
        person.id = 1;
        person.address = "\"952 NW 80th St, Miami, FL 33150\"";
        person.name = "Jeff";
        person.age = 30;
        person.isEmployed = true;

        System.out.println("personInfo = " + toStringRemovingClassName(person));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
personInfo = id=0, name=null, age=null, isEmployed=null, address=null
personInfo = id=1, name=Jeff, age=30, isEmployed=true, address="952 NW 80th St, Miami, FL 33150"
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

You need to `override` `toString()` method in your `POJO` class like below:

```
    @Data
    public class Person {
        public int id;
        public String name;
        public Integer age;
        public Boolean isEmployed;
        public String address;

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "id=" + id + ",name=" + name +",age=" + age + ",isEmployed=" + isEmployed + ",address=" + address;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One could use Apache `commons-lang3` lib's `org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder` capability and specify a style without the class name, e.g.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return new ToStringBuilder(this, ToStringStyle.NO_CLASS_NAME_STYLE)
           .append("id", id)
           .append("name", name)
           .append("age", age)
           .toString()
}
```

Output: `[id=1,name=John,age=20]`